# response data from $resource service into controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm coding an app that 'talks' to RESTfull server and I'm having some problems. Here's the stripped down version of my code: https://gist.github.com/sasxa/ced4ecfa2a147b207cac, and some questions:

1) How do I process custom JSON format my server returns? $resource seams to 'demand' clean data... For example:

```
// This works
response = [{...}, {...}, {...}]

// This doesn't work
response = { status: 'OK', data: [{...}, {...}, {...}], message: 'Hello!' }
```

As I understand it, $resorce.query() is a promise, generated during transformResponse phase, but I can't find my message anywhere in this object.

I started looking into $http interceptors and I think I could process response from the server there, but I have no idea how to pass that data to the service (other then *data* as an array of resources) or to the controller...

2) Is there a better solution for loading templates dynamically then the one I'm using?

```
angular.module( 'APPLICATION' )
    .config( ['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when( '/:node', {
        template: '<section ng-controller="Controller" ng-include="template"></section>',
        controller: 'Controller'
      } );
    }] )
```

3) Any advice or comments on code structure and organization? I'm pretty new to the AngularJS. I read and watched many tutorials, just wanna make sure I'm not making any big mistakes (:

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to modify the value with transformData, just access it directly when you make your query call

   `MyResource.query({}, function(result) { 
     $log.info(result.status);
     $log.info(result.data);
     $log.info(result.message);
   });`

   You also need to make sure that you configure your $resource to expect an Object as a result, rather than an Array (default). You can do that like this:

   `$resource('<someurl>/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
     'query' : { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
   });`
2. You can use the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache) to store your templates in javascript, and then use a templateUrl in your routeProvider
3. There is a great google doc tracking the current best practice for angular app layouts over [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub).

I also strongly suggest you look at a project like [ngbp](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp), to get a better idea of how to put your whole app together

Comment: 1) The thing is when I return object formatted response I'm getting an error "Error: $resource:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter". I couldn't track down what's responsible for it, I just changed server code and returned clean data to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a look.

Comment: Ah, your problem is that you have to define the resource so it expects an Object instead of an Arrray. I'll edit my answer

Comment: yep, that's it.. **isArray: false** solves my problems (: thanks!